# Remove zeros from Date string

Tags: javascript, regex, date

I have a string with the following format: '01/02/2016' and I am trying to get rid of the leading zeros so that at the end I get '1/2/2016' with regex.

Tried `'01/02/2016'.replace(/^0|[^\/]0./, '');` so far, but it only gives me `1/02/2016`

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: not complete duplicate and don't flag  [Remove leading zeroes in datestring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8897298/remove-leading-zeroes-in-datestring)

Comment: Apart from missing `g` flag, the `^` doesn't mean "start of" when used inside `[]`.

Comment: You could replace `[^\/]` with `\/`, but mbomb007's answer is better as it supports any separator, not just "/". ;-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Replace `\b0` with empty string. `\b` represents the border between a word character and a non-word character. In your case, `\b0` will match a leading zero.

```js
var d = '01/02/2016'.replace(/\b0/g, '');
console.log(d); // 1/2/2016

var d = '10/30/2020'.replace(/\b0/g, '');
console.log(d); // 10/30/2020 (stays the same)
```

Comment: @JonathanPotter No it doesn't. Did you even run the code snippet? If you add a carat, it won't remove zeros from the middle number, so `01/02/2016` would become `1/02/2016`, which is the exact thing the OP wanted to fix.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and regular expression to replace the zero at the binning and the zero before `/` like this:

```js
var d = '01/02/2016'.replace(/(^|\/)0+/g, '$1');
console.log(d);
```

Comment: also just realized I can use moment for that since I already have a dependency in my project moment('01/02/2016').format('l')

Comment: Yep, if you are already are using the library Moment that is a good answer!!

Comment: I am actually trying to find what 'l' is stands for, would you know by any chance? can't find in moment docs