# How to get Format Date from Input?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have input control for date field. I wish to date format like `2/2/2019` .In below code `output` is : 02/02/2019

**Sample Code:**

```js
var date = new Date($('#AppointmentDate').val());
var formatted = ('00' + date.getDate()).slice(-2) + '/' + ('00' + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '/' + date.getFullYear();

console.log(formatted);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Appointment Date must be a date." id="AppointmentDate" name="AppointmentDate" type="hidden" value="02/02/19 12:00:00 AM">
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove leading zeroes in datestring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8897298/remove-leading-zeroes-in-datestring)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get String in YYYYMMDD format from JS date object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066586/get-string-in-yyyymmdd-format-from-js-date-object)

Comment: No it isn't a dublicate of the links you provided. The first link is asking for a replacement of zeros for an already given string. The second one is just asking for how to get a string out of an object.

Answer (score 2):

Your code appends 0's if the date is smaller than 10. Simply remove that code:

```js
var date = new Date($('#AppointmentDate').val());
var formatDate =getFormattedDate(date);
console.log(formatDate);

function getFormattedDate(date) {
  var year = date.getFullYear();

  var month = (1 + date.getMonth()).toString();

  var day = date.getDate().toString();
  
  return month + '/' + day + '/' + year;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Appointment Date must be a date." id="AppointmentDate" name="AppointmentDate" type="hidden" value="2/2/19 12:00:00 AM">
```

To your edit, again, remove the code that is adding the zero's:

```js
var date = new Date($('#AppointmentDate').val());
var formatted = ('' + date.getDate()).slice(-2) + '/' + ('' + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '/' + date.getFullYear();

console.log(formatted);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Appointment Date must be a date." id="AppointmentDate" name="AppointmentDate" type="hidden" value="02/02/19 12:00:00 AM">
```

Comment: No problem. If you ever need more help, feel free to ask.

Answer (score -1):

you could use `parseInt` to remove preceeding zeros